# set automatic width of headers inside ul without line breaks

Tags: html, css, width, line-breaks

How can I set an automatic width of an element (in my case the `h3` of an `ul`) without putting line breaks, so the text fits automatically inside the container within that width, letting only the height change accordingly?

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you please explain your question further? Are you asking "How do I make the width take up the full space?"

Comment: I just want to set a specific width for a container containing the header (h3) and no matter how long the text is, it fits automatically inside, without going over the border of the container and wtihout me typing <br/> everytime I need to start a new paragraph. I hope I have explained it better. thank you btw.

Answer (score 0):

To give a container a specific width, you can just set the width of the `<ul>` tag.

To do this you use the `width` property in CSS.

In the below example I have set the `width` to be `400px`, you can adjust this according to your need.

```css
.list {
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
<li>
<h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In mattis, est id malesuada ultrices, tortor augue suscipit ex, nec viverra diam purus sit amet purus. </p>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now my last problem. I already have an <ul> in my document with specific  css properties. In order for me to tell the browser to give specific properties to this second <ul>, different from the first <ul>, can I specify a "class" for it? or are thre other and better ways for this? Because I did and it didn't work...thks

Comment: Yes you should definitely give it a class or an id. If you give it a class for example `<ul class="classname"` then you need to do in the styling `.classname` and then style it like that. I will update my answer with this for you.